# Integrate tutorial code into generated NavigationView code

Tags: android

Learning android and now I'm stuck with a simple problem.

I started a new project with menu slide

```
package com.naradanews.naradanews;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now this is tutorial code

```
package com.learn2crack.tab;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
             public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }};
            //Add New Tab
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Android").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("iOS").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Windows").setTabListener(tabListener));

    }

}
```

see in both MainActivity extending with different class. am asking how integrate tutorial with my  code.

Comment: the problem is every tutorial MainActivity class extend with different class. I am asking how to do all this thing when creating a app. no screen shot bcz i can't start coding :) bcz of this issue. i tried separate extend for fragment class with mainactivity but it showing duplicate class :(

Comment: did you finished one of theese tutorials. Also did you read [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). You can create custom class that extends `Fragment` and add it to your `MainActivity`. Maybe add your tutorial link. No link and no screenshot , cant imagine what are you trying !

Comment: In Java, you can only extends from one class. It would be much more helpful, if you describe what do you want to achieve in general.

Comment: wow people are awsome here <3,  so, fast reply am pasting my complete code.

Comment: AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity... Besides the fact you can't do it, you don't need multiple extensions

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to use `TabLayout` together with a `ViewPager`.

Here's a simple example for you to get started on and maybe help you understand better how it works.

In your `MainActivity` you will call `setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_activity)` in `onCreate()`.

That xml can look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then in your `MainActivity` you will initialise these widgets in `onCreate`:

```
mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
```

For this view pager you will need an adapter to handle the tabs (fragments in this case):

```
public class ViewPagerTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<String> mTabTitles;
    private List<Fragment> mFragments;

    public ViewPagerTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mTabTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTabTitles.get(position);
    }

    public void addTab(int pos, String title, Fragment fragment) {
        mTabTitles.add(pos, title);
        mFragments.add(pos, fragment);
    }
}
```

And then in your `MainActivity#onCreate` you'll add the tabs (fragments) to the adapter followed by setting it all up:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private TabLayout mTabLayout;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_activity);

            mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

            ViewPagerTabsAdapter pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            pagerAdapter.addTab(0, "Tab 1", new Fragment());
            pagerAdapter.addTab(1, "Tab 2", new Fragment());

            mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
            mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        }
}
```

You said that you were a beginner but here's a tutorial which takes you through a lot of things regarding this. I think if you read it carefully you'll manage to solve your problem.
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

But you should probably also read some about activities and fragments.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html